# change button text onclick

Tags: jquery

We are using Quicksand ( the sortable filterbale quicksand plugin )

Anyhoo..

Apart from the normal filters, to initiate the quicksand animation. We also can display the individual < li > 's by using a sweet little Layout Switcher.

The code of which is:

```
<!-- layout switcher -->
    <div id="layoutSwitcher">
        <a id="buttonsend" class="notsosmall pink button">More Info</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /end layout switcher -->
```

But my issue is If active I want to display Less Info.

In normal state to show More Info.

I am positive we can do this using jQuery

The jQuery to control the switcher is:

```
jQuery('#layoutSwitcher a').myPortfolioLayoutSwitcher({
    show_switcher: true,
    full_width_layout: false 
});
```

So my question is simply.. can we change button text onclick to display **less info** or **more info** as necessary.

my

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy Peasy. You just need to toggle between two text spans.

```
 <a id="buttonsend" class="notsosmall pink button">
     <span>More Info</span>
     <span style="display:none">Less Info</span>
 </a>
```

and some JS

```
$('a#buttonsend').click(function() {
    $('span',this).toggle();
});
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/m9zxx/

Comment: Perfect thanks :) have changed first $ to jQuery , thats correct isnt it ?

Comment: Yep, $ and jQuery are interchangeable. If you are using another library in addition to library its best to use jQuery rather than $

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that plugin works like jquery's inherent toggle method, toggle should work.

```
jQuery('#layoutSwitcher a').myPortfolioLayoutSwitcher({
    show_switcher: true,
    full_width_layout: false 
}).toggle(
    function(){jQuery(this).html('show less');},
    function(){jQuery(this).html('show more');});
```